# Firefox has two default profiles: "default-release" and "default". Which one should I choose?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

Guess what, "default" is not my default profile. That would be "default-release".

Can I delete "default"? What's the reason for the double profile?

Comment: Found a similar question with answer: https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1264072

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer at *[Is the 'default-release' profile a bug or the new profile name for Firefox 67 upwards and still being phased in?](https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1264072)*.

**Summary of that page**

Firefox can't share profiles between separate installs since v67.

The two profiles, .default and .default-release, are used by installs from different update channels - like release, beta, nightly, developer-edition, etc. So for a non-tech user, .default-release is the "normal" default, since it is dedicated to the "normal" Release channel.

Older version of Firefox used .default in place of .default-release, so if you have both it's probably because you have first installed Firefox before v67. The old .default profile was converted and copied to .default-release when you updated to Firefox 67.

Comment: Nope. Installed v89. It also has two profiles.

Comment: i just did a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 and it installed firefox 92.0 with these two profiles.

Comment: I have a macOS system that was new in January of this year, and it too has the two profiles. I also have an older machine that's been around since long before Firefox 67 and it only has one profile (default). This machine has never had different installs, at least not by my intention.

Comment: I agree with the Firefox software release channels 'release' 'beta' 'nightly' 'developer-edition'. I installed the developer edition, and suddenly that profile started showing up in my main Firefox installation. This means they're still sharing profiles.--or, it means the developer-edition is not technically a separate installation.